# MySQL Desktop Based Administration

Tags: mysql, desktop-application

I am making a MySQL based database for a professor and she would like to have a version uploaded to the web and a version on her desktop for personal use. The web version would be "official" whereas the one on her desktop would be used for personal research and would have additional categories, etc. The two databases do not have to be linked but I was unsure if it would be easier to put both databases on the web and make her personal one password protected or if there was a good desktop based program. She is not very tech-savvy which is why I was leaning away from having her install MySQL and Apache on her own desktop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install MySQL Workbench and then setup a connection to access the remote one, and also you can a have a local mysql with a dump of the db. Both db's can be handled using the [MySQL Workbench tool](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official MySQL Administration tool: [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)